# Troubleshooting; Creating Alias in MySQL

Tags: mysql, alias

I am using MySQL on Mac Yosemite Beta 10.10. Trying to create an alias that selects FirstName plus LastName to create an alias of 'Full Name'. Results are inaccurate; FullName does appear, however, there is a '0' in each row where there should be FirstName + Lastname.

Comment: Do you have of the attempts you've made to showcase?

Comment: Are you using an actual `+` instead of a `CONCAT()`?

Comment: Am using a + Wrikken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CONCAT_WS**: Concatenate With Separator

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstName, LastName) AS FullName FROM ...
```